# AngularStrap popover: Object popover has no method on

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-strap

I'm trying to integrate AngularStrap popover in my app. I have the following code on the button:

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-popover="views/login.html" data-unique="1" data-placement="bottom">
        <span>Login</span>
    </button>
```

I have the appropriate dependencies added to my app. When I try to execute this on Chrome, I get the following in the console:

```
    TypeError: Object popover has no method 'on'
```

It also says this:

```
    TypeError: Object tooltip has no method 'on'
```

What am I missing? I'd really appreciate it if someone can post a working code sample here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mix ui-bootstrap and mgcrea.ngStrap? This happened when ui-bootstrap invokes tooltip from mgcrea.ngStrap:

```
return $tooltip( 'popover', 'popover', 'click' );
```